# How to grouping row value in some conditional postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have query like this:

```
SELECT user_input_id, 
question_id,
type,
question,
COALESCE(value_text, value_free_text, value_date::text, value_number::text, value) AS all_value
FROM(
SELECT 
a.id, 
a.user_input_id,
d.id as question_id, 
d.type,
d.matrix_subtype,
d.question, 
a.value_suggested_row, 
c.value as matrix_questions, 
a.value_suggested,
b.value,
a.value_text, 
a.value_free_text,
a.value_date,
a.value_number
FROM survey_user_input_line a 
LEFT JOIN survey_label b on b.id = a.value_suggested
LEFT JOIN survey_label c on c.id = a.value_suggested_row
LEFT JOIN survey_question d on d.id = a.question_id
LEFT JOIN survey_user_input e on e.id = a.user_input_id
WHERE a.survey_id = 6
ORDER BY question_id, a.user_input_id,  id, value_suggested_row) as TempTable
```

and this result:

[image]

I would like to grouping row where type is multiple_choice

and my wish result like this:

[image]

Can Anyone Help Me?

Comment: Sample data is better presented as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would split your result into two part (with and without `multiple_choice`) and `UNION` them after grouping the `multiple_choice` part:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM (--<your query>) s
WHERE type != 'multiple_choice'

UNION

SELECT
    user_input_id,
    question_id,
    type,
    question,
    STRING_AGG(all_value, ',')
FROM (--<your query>) s
WHERE type = 'multiple_choice'
GROUP BY user_input_id, question_id, type, question
```

---

It could be more performant to put your subquery into a CTE:

```
WITH my_cte AS (                       
    -- <your query>
)
SELECT
    *
FROM my_cte 
WHERE type != 'multiple_choice'

UNION

SELECT
    user_input_id,
    question_id,
    type,
    question,
    STRING_AGG(all_value, ',')
FROM my_cte
WHERE type = 'multiple_choice'
GROUP BY user_input_id, question_id, type, question
```

Comment: Thank a lot for your tips @S-Man