# How to add counter id column based on several columns on SELECT query Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I would like to create a column with counter number based on `question_id` and `matrix_question_id` this is my query:

```
WITH cte_survey AS 
(
    SELECT 
        user_input_id, 
        question_id,
        type,
        matrix_subtype,
        question,
        matrix_question_id,
        matrix_questions,
        COALESCE(value_text, value_free_text, value_date::text, value_number::text, value) AS all_value
    FROM
        (SELECT 
             a.id, a.user_input_id,
             d.id as question_id, d.type,
             d.matrix_subtype,
             d.question, 
             a.value_suggested_row,
             c.id as matrix_question_id,
             c.value as matrix_questions, 
             a.value_suggested,
             b.value,
             a.value_text, 
             a.value_free_text,
             a.value_date,
             a.value_number
         FROM 
             survey_user_input_line a 
         LEFT JOIN 
             survey_label b on b.id = a.value_suggested
         LEFT JOIN 
             survey_label c on c.id = a.value_suggested_row
         LEFT JOIN 
             survey_question d on d.id = a.question_id
         LEFT JOIN 
             survey_user_input e on e.id = a.user_input_id
         WHERE 
             a.survey_id = 6
         ORDER BY 
             question_id, user_input_id,  matrix_question_id, value_suggested_row) AS TempTable
)
SELECT 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY question_id) AS id, * 
FROM
    (SELECT *
     FROM cte_survey 
     WHERE type != 'multiple_choice'

     UNION
 
     SELECT 
         user_input_id, question_id, type,
         matrix_subtype, question, 
         matrix_question_id, matrix_questions,
         STRING_AGG(all_value, ',')
     FROM 
         cte_survey
     WHERE 
         type = 'multiple_choice'
     GROUP BY 
         user_input_id, question_id, type, question, matrix_subtype,
         question, matrix_question_id, matrix_questions
     ORDER BY 
         question_id, matrix_question_id, user_input_id) AS result_answer
```

and this is the [result](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1JMoOcYvgysANyV2DYYg1bEHkwAyGIdNNsV0B1BOBUio/edit?usp=sharing)

I would like to create a new column as `id_counter` represent id counter base on question_id and matrix_question_id and I wish the result like [this](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Urqhc0iel2rbjA11KeXHs7xThLD629v26h8Cox9KK0o/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: `DEMSE_RANK() OVER...` maybe? By the way, I'd love to know why you are using `UNION` and not `UNION ALL`

Comment: because I want to avoid duplicate row

Comment: But you are anyway filtering on `type = 'multiple_choice'` and `!=` so they are never going to be the same? But you haven't given me the data, so I guess you will know better what you need, I just see people often using `UNION` needlessly

Comment: by the way I filtering on type because I folow this tutorial: (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66130290/how-to-grouping-row-value-in-some-conditional-postgresql/66133038#66133038)

Comment: Thank for your tips, DENSE_RANK() OVER() is work for this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need here is `DENSE_RANK`, you can place this next to your `row_number`:

```sql
DENSE_RANK() over (ORDER BY question_id) as id_counter
```

Further points:

1. If there is no chance that the two halves of the query can overlap, the `UNION ALL` will be more efficient than `UNION`
2. The `row_number` is non-deterministic and may return different results each time. You should add an extra ordering clause, perhaps `question_id, matrix_question_id, user_input_id` or some other unique combination.
3. `ORDER BY` on the results of a derived table, view or CTE is not guaranteed to work (unless you are using it with `LIMIT`, or inside a ranking or window function). You should only place on the very outside of your query.
4. The very first `TempTable` seems pointless, you could merge it all directly inside your CTE.